# how to create controls that requires properties in other controls?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I was just creating a Windows form that uses a [ToolTip](http://127.0.0.1/help/1/ms.help?method=page&id=82E71DC3-0159-4F91-9F22-499224F004A0&SQM=1&product=VS&productVersion=100&locale=en-US) control and it occurred to me that this control (or component to be right on the terminology) provides design time properties for every other control on the form.

How can I achieve this for a control of my design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That bit of magic is created by inheriting and implementing the IExtenderProvider interface.   It is pretty easy to do, the designer is doing all the heavy lifting.  There's a very good How To in this [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6c1xa43.aspx).