# How can I add a property to System.Windows.Form.Control in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, properties, controls, tooltip, base-class

Is there a way to add a property to System.Windows.Form.Control base class without defining the new inherited class (in VB.NET) ?

I want to add a Tooltip property to all of System.Windows.Form.Control controls, which will be browsable in properties window of that control.

Comment: The ToolTip component already works this way.  Note how it adds the "ToolTip on" property to every control.

Comment: yes, I already noticed that. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create controls that requires properties in other controls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183356/how-to-create-controls-that-requires-properties-in-other-controls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to write an [extender provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6c1xa43.aspx).